# "Unused import warning" and pylint

Tags: python, warnings, pylint

So I'm working on a project in Python and trying to keep it up to standards with pylint and just generally .  So, I have a source file, (We'll just call it a.py)

```
#a.py
import loggingsetup

def foo():
   log.info("This is a log message")
```

But, I want to control what the logging looks like, so in loggingsetup I have something like:

```
#loggingsetup.py
import logging

logging.root.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

consoleOut = logging.StreamHandler()
consoleOut.setLevel(logging.INFO)  
consoleOut.setFormatter(logging.Formatter("\t"+logging.BASIC_FORMAT))
logging.root.addHandler(consoleOut)

#etc
```

Now, this seems to work alright.  I suppose as a preliminary question I should ask if this is the right way to go about this, or if there's a different way of structuring my code that would be preferable.

But my main question is that when I run pylint on a.py I get a warning like "unused import - import loggingsetup", since I'm not actually calling any methods or functions from loggingsetup.

I could do something like redefine the body of loggingsetup as a function and call it, but it seems silly and error-prone (I'd have to worry about calling it twice if I did import loggingsetup from somewhere else, and if I understand how python handles imports, that's not an issue with my current setup).

I could obviously just tell pylint to ignore the warning, but I thought I'd ask here first to make sure that this isn't actually something that I should handle differently.

Comment: Importing a module just for its side effects feels wrong to me.  It makes the intent of your code harder to discern.  Explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: It's just a warning that you may have forgotten something and/or may be doing something unnecessary. Ignore it if that's not the case.

Comment: I sort of disagree with the above sentiment from martineau.  Yes, sometimes this is how it goes, and you have to ignore warnings, but usually warnings shouldn't be treated as "friendly reminders" and ignored without being certain, which is why I came to either make certain I could ignore it, or get a better approach.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The approach I would use is to use `loggingsetup` as a sort of wrapper for `logging`.

```
import logging

# set up logging config here

from logging import *
```

Then in your other modules you:

```
import loggingsetup as logging
```

You might want to use a name other than `loggingsetup` in this case, e.g. `tweaked_logging` or `logging_with_my_settings`.

Comment: From the perspective of my original warning, that works, and I definitely like this idea.  Now I've got pylint complaining about the wildcard import, and all the unused imports in loggingsetup.py (though I took your advice and renamed it)

Comment: I've not tried this, but putting `# pylint: disable-msg-cat=` comment at the top of your wrapper module should let you suppress specified categories of warnings in that module only. At least you've isolated all the "badness" to one module.  :-)

Answer (score 44):

If you use `pylint` *and* `flake8` you can ignore unused import warning in both tools in this way:

```
import loggingsetup  # noqa # pylint: disable=unused-import
```

Comment: It seems that you need *two spaces* before the beginning of the "second comment": `  # noqa  # pylint: disable=unused-import`

Answer (score 40):

In such cases, you can still explicitly tell pylint that this unused import in intended:

```
import loggingsetup # pylint: disable=unused-import
```

Notice the  instruction is on the same line as the import so W0611 is only disabled for this line, and not for all the block below.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Instead, I used `# noqa # pylint: disable=unused-import` and it worked.

Answer (score 5):

As you have mentioned yourself wrapping it in a function and calling the setup explicitly would resolve this warning. And as Steven mentioned, this would be considered better code since it is more explicit about what you are doing.

If you worry about calling this function twice, you can of course use a module intern flag to allow execution of the function body only once.

```
__initialized = False

def init():
    if not __initialized:
        __initialized = True
        #DoStuff
```

Comment: Right, and this would work, but I can't help but feel that it sort of sacrifices "Simple is better than complex" to do it this way.  

Not would it be wrapping the body of the script, but I'd also have to remember to add the function call to any imports.  Not terrible, but not as simple.

It would be a good option in some cases, but in this case, I think kindall's answer is the better one.

Answer (score 4):

your code should be in a function called once in the main script

Answer (score 3):

I had a long path for the import and it spanned across multiple lines due to restrictions on the line size. I had to make sure that `# noqa` was used on the first line of the import rather than the last. E.g.

```
from this.could.be.a.very.long.path import (  # noqa
some_method,
)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can also just

```
assert loggingsetup
```

to get the linters off your back