# 'Unable to import' errors for anaconda environment in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda, conda, pylint

I am trying to solve partial differential equations with Python using [FEniCS](https://fenicsproject.org/). I installed it with `anaconda` and `conda-forge` and to use it, I activate the `fenicsproject` environment

```
source activate fenicsproject
```

I run my scripts in `jupyter` (that works), but often it is more convenient to use VS Code for more elaborate code. When I run the scripts written in VS Code in the (built-in) terminal, they run without error as long as I have the `fenicsproject` environment enabled.

But in the editor I get a lot of errors like this

`[pylint] Unable to import '...' [E0401]'`
`[pylint] Undefined variable '...' [E0602]`

How can I get rid of those errors in the editor, so that the real errors can stand out.
What would be even better, make it that auto-complete and suggestions work for the packages like `fenics`, `mshr` etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio Code pylint: Unable to import 'protorpc'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574995/visual-studio-code-pylint-unable-to-import-protorpc)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [the Python in Visual Studio Code docs](https://donjayamanne.github.io/pythonVSCodeDocs/docs/troubleshooting_linting/), this is probably due to Visual Studio Code pointing at the wrong Python version.

> #### 1. Unable to import  (pylint)
>
> - Scenario: You have a module installed, however the linter in the IDE is complaining about; not being able to import the module, hence error
>     messages such as the following are displayed as linter errors:
>
>   ```
>   .. unable to import 'xxx' ..
>   ```
> - Cause: The Python extension is most likely using the wrong version of Pylint.
>
> **Solution 1: (configure workspace settings to point to fully qualified python executable):**
>
> 1. Open the workspace settings (settings.json)
> 2. Identify the fully qualified path to the python executable (this could even be a virtual environment)
> 3. Ensure Pylint is installed for the above python environment
> 4. Configure the setting "pythonPath" to point to (previously identified) the fully qualified python executable.
>
>    ````
>    "python.pythonPath": "/users/xxx/bin/python" ```
>    ````
>
> **Solution 2: (open VS Code from an activated virtual environment):**
>
> 1. Open the terminal window
> 2. Activate the relevant python virtual environment
> 3. Ensure Pylint is installed within this virtual environment
>
>    ```
>    pip install pylint
>    ```
> 4. Close all instances of VS Code
> 5. Launch VS Code from within this terminal window
>      (this will ensure the VS Code process will inherit all of the Virtual Env environment settings)

Comment: That works. I tried both solutions, both of them resolve the initial problem (after installing `pylint` in the environment, i.e. `conda install pylint`). For solution 1: I activated the environment, got the path with `which python` and added it to the workspace settings.

Comment: However, it does not get rid of all warnings/errors, more precise I get different ones:  
warning: `[pylint] Unused import ... from wildcart import [W0614]` I could get rid of this one by adding `# pylint: disable=unused-import` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11957106/unused-import-warning-and-pylint (but only for solution 2 !?!) and error: `[pylint] Instance of ... has no ... member [E1101]` even though the method/property exists

Comment: That's an actual problem with your code. :-) Don't use wildcard imports; they're horrible.

Comment: Okay :) will change that. But the errors with `Instance of ... has no ... member` are on packages with non-wildcard imports, e.g. `from matplotlib import cm`

Comment: @josh21 Hmm... That's probably something it should be able to deal with, but `pylint` would have no clue with C stuff (where there's no Python source available). Is that the cause?

Comment: I just added `generated-members=cm.*` to `.pylintrc` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33961756/disabling-pylint-no-member-e1101-error-for-specific-libraries not sure if that is good solution, but for now I have at least no errors showing

Comment: @josh21 Did it fix it?

Comment: Don't think it is a proper "fix" (since the member is still not recognized), but at least there are no errors anymore and I can focus on the actual work

Answer (score 3):

A slight correction to "Solution 1" above: use

````
"python.defaultInterpreterPath": "/users/xxx/bin/python" ```
````

source: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/wiki/Setting-descriptions#pythondefaultinterpreterpath